# @media screen not doing anything at all for my class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to adjust two CSS classes when my window is no wider than 750px. I'm trying to target three-column-grid & content-box. For some reason, three-column-grid works perfectly. But Content-box does nothing at all.

```css
.content-wrapper {
  padding:2em;
}.content{
  background-color:#000;
  padding:1em;
  margin-top:4em;
  margin-bottom:5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5d4a26;
  border-top: 3px solid #5d4a26;
  opacity:0.9;

  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position: center center center;
}
.content-box{
  width:60%;
  text-align:left;
  background-color:black;
  border: 1px solid #121212;
  opacity:0.7;
  padding:10px;
}

.three-column-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   .three-columns{
     display:grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   }

   .content-box{
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid #121212;
    opacity:0.7;
    padding:10px;
  }

 }
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                    <div class="content-box"><h2>{{content.0.title}}</h2>
                            <p>{{content.0.content}}</p></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

### update

In the isolated code I posted it seems to work. But in the context of my full, it does not seem to work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=EB+Garamond&family=Syne+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<style>

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family: 'Syne Mono', monospace;
  /* font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif; */
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height:1.8em;
  color:white;
  background-color: #121212;;
}

.banner {
    background-image: url('/static/core/images/earth_gold.jpg');
    background-size:     100%;                      /* <------ */
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center center;
    height:0;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 51.4%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}

.banner1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #96763c;
}

.banner > img{
  width:100%;
}

.particles-js {
    height:200px;
    background-color: black;
}

.large_text{
  font-size:27px;
  letter-spacing:8px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: white;
}

.border {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-color:#96763c;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;

}

.content-wrapper {
  padding:2em;
}.content{
  background-color:#000;
  padding:1em;
  margin-top:4em;
  margin-bottom:5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5d4a26;
  border-top: 3px solid #5d4a26;
  opacity:0.9;

  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position: center center center;
}
.history{
  background-image:url('/static/core/images/satellite.jpg');

}
.mission{
  background-image:url('/static/core/images/mars.jpg');
  display: flex;
  justify-content:right;
  justify-items:right;

}
.content-box{
  width:60%;
  text-align:left;
  background-color:black;
  border: 1px solid #121212;
  opacity:0.7;
  padding:10px;
}

.panel-box {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid #121212;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding:10px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:left;
  text-align:left;
  grid-row:2/3;

}
.panel-title{
  border-left: 1px solid #5d4a26;
  border-right: 1px solid #5d4a26;
  height: auto;
}

.three-columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:1em;
}

.panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  min-height:80px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding:1em;
  border: 1px dotted #5d4a26;
  text-align:center;
}
.panel-employee {
  min-height:80px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding:1em;
  border: 1px dotted #5d4a26;
  text-align:center;
}

.panel:hover {
  border: 1px solid #5d4a26;
}


.image-cropper {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.image-cropper>img{
  width:100%;
}
.image-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:2em;
}
h2{
  color: #cac8c5;
}
h3 {
  color: #afadaa;
}

.countdown-wrapper{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:black;
  background-image:url('./images/gradient.jpg');
  background-size:contain;
  opacity:0.8;
  margin:2em;
  align-self:bottom;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.countdown{
  display:grid;
}
.countdown>div{
  padding:5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2.3em;
  font-family: 'Syne Mono', monospace;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.countdown>div:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.launchbox{
  margin-bottom:-70px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
  width: 50%;
  opacity:0.6;
  background-color:black;
  font-size:27px;
  letter-spacing:8px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: white;
  padding:1em;
  border: 1px solid #96763c;
}

.button {
  padding: 0.6em;
  border: 1px dotted #96763c;
  min-width:150px;
  flex:1;
}
.button:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.button_wrapper {
  width:40%;
  display:flex;
  margin-top:-3em;
}
.dark{
  background-color:black;
  opacity:0.7;
}
.button_wrapper>div{
  margin: 1em;
}

   @media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   .three-columns{
     display:grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   }

   .content-box{
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid #121212;
    opacity:0.7;
    padding:10px;
  }

 }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/core/style.css">
      <script src="/static/core/node_modules/countdown/countdown.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/core/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js"></script>
    </head> 
    
    <body>
            
        <div class="particles-js" id="particles-js"></div>
        <script>
            particlesJS.load('particles-js', "/static/core/particles.json", function() {
            console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });
        </script>
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="border">
                    <span class="large_text">Geometric Space Corporation</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content history">
                    <div class="content-box"><h2>History</h2>
                            <p>(GSC) is a recently formed subsidiary of Geometric Energy Corporation, a research and development firm founded in 2015. GSC provides cost-effective CubeSat rideshare programs, dedicated FireFly Alpha launches, and satellite data services.</p></div>
            </div>
            <center>
            <div class="launchbox">Countdown to Launch</div>
            <div class="countdown-wrapper"><div class="countdown" id="timer"></div></div> 
            <div class="button_wrapper"><div class="button dark">About This Launch</div><div class="button dark">Launch Schedule</div>
</div>
            </center>
            <div class="content mission">
                    <div class="content-box"><h2>Mission</h2>
                            <p>GSC ultimate ambition is to contribute to the creation of a multiplanetary civilization. The intermediary steps include optimizing current technology and expanding the commercial space market. It is those latter tasks on which the company is currently concentrating.</p></div>
            </div>
            <h1>Our Projects:</h1>
            <div class="three-columns">
                    
                    <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-title"><h2>Satellite Launch Services</h2></div>
                            <div class="panel-box">In 2021, Geometric Space launches Terraporta, the flagship software-as-a-service (SAAS) product capable of integrating with satellite data feeds from NASA, ESA, and JAXA.</div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-title"><h2>Dedicated FIrefly Alpha Launches</h2></div>
                            <div class="panel-box">In collaboration with our launch service provider, Firefly Aerospace, Geometric Space facilitates missions to low earth orbit for US and Canadian universities, private corporations, and government agencies.</div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-title"><h2>Rideshare Programs for CubeSat Integration</h2></div>
                            <div class="panel-box">Geometric Space provides US and Canadian companies an affordable barrier for entry into the space market. Through an innovative blend of CubeSat form factor type payloads, multi-party integration, and mission cost optimization, Geometric Space minimizes financial requirements for space start-ups.</div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                    </div>
                    
            </div>
            <h1>The Team:</h1>
            <div class="three-columns">
                 
                <div class="panel-employee"><div class="image-wrapper"><div class="image-cropper"><img src="/media/employee_photos/sam-bf464855cdfd07858ca09ebf6b65d982.jpg" /></div></div><h2>Dan Ted</h2><h3>CTO</h3><div class="panel-box">Dan is the man ok just accept it</div></div>
                 
            </div>
</div>
<script> 
        var time = countdown(function(ts){
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML=ts.toHTML('div').replace(/,|and/gi,'')
        },new Date(2022, 6, 1), countdown.DAYS|countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over the updated full code you posted, there isn't a media query for `.content-box` within the internal `<style>` tags in your HTML. I did see an external stylesheet link,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/core/style.css">
```

If the media query is declared in that external stylesheet, then the issue could be in there.

Nonetheless, I added the `(max-width: 750px)` media query to the bottom of your internal `<style>` tag and the media condition works as expected for `.content-box` when the viewport width is less than 750px.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=EB+Garamond&family=Syne+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<style>

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family: 'Syne Mono', monospace;
  /* font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif; */
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height:1.8em;
  color:white;
  background-color: #121212;;
}

.banner {
    background-image: url('/static/core/images/earth_gold.jpg');
    background-size:     100%;                      /* <------ */
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center center;
    height:0;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 51.4%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}

.banner1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #96763c;
}

.banner > img{
  width:100%;
}

.particles-js {
    height:200px;
    background-color: black;
}

.large_text{
  font-size:27px;
  letter-spacing:8px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: white;
}

.border {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-color:#96763c;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;

}

.content-wrapper {
  padding:2em;
}.content{
  background-color:#000;
  padding:1em;
  margin-top:4em;
  margin-bottom:5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5d4a26;
  border-top: 3px solid #5d4a26;
  opacity:0.9;

  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position: center center center;
}
.history{
  background-image:url('/static/core/images/satellite.jpg');

}
.mission{
  background-image:url('/static/core/images/mars.jpg');
  display: flex;
  justify-content:right;
  justify-items:right;

}
.content-box{
  width:60%;
  text-align:left;
  background-color:black;
  border: 1px solid #121212;
  opacity:0.7;
  padding:10px;
}

.panel-box {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid #121212;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding:10px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:left;
  text-align:left;
  grid-row:2/3;

}
.panel-title{
  border-left: 1px solid #5d4a26;
  border-right: 1px solid #5d4a26;
  height: auto;
}

.three-columns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:1em;
}

.panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  min-height:80px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding:1em;
  border: 1px dotted #5d4a26;
  text-align:center;
}
.panel-employee {
  min-height:80px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding:1em;
  border: 1px dotted #5d4a26;
  text-align:center;
}

.panel:hover {
  border: 1px solid #5d4a26;
}


.image-cropper {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.image-cropper>img{
  width:100%;
}
.image-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:2em;
}
h2{
  color: #cac8c5;
}
h3 {
  color: #afadaa;
}

.countdown-wrapper{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:black;
  background-image:url('./images/gradient.jpg');
  background-size:contain;
  opacity:0.8;
  margin:2em;
  align-self:bottom;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.countdown{
  display:grid;
}
.countdown>div{
  padding:5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2.3em;
  font-family: 'Syne Mono', monospace;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.countdown>div:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.launchbox{
  margin-bottom:-70px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
  width: 50%;
  opacity:0.6;
  background-color:black;
  font-size:27px;
  letter-spacing:8px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: white;
  padding:1em;
  border: 1px solid #96763c;
}

.button {
  padding: 0.6em;
  border: 1px dotted #96763c;
  min-width:150px;
  flex:1;
}
.button:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.button_wrapper {
  width:40%;
  display:flex;
  margin-top:-3em;
}
.dark{
  background-color:black;
  opacity:0.7;
}
.button_wrapper>div{
  margin: 1em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   .three-columns{
     display:grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   }

   .content-box {
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #121212;
    opacity:0.7;
    padding:10px;
  }

 }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/core/style.css">
      <script src="/static/core/node_modules/countdown/countdown.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/core/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js"></script>
    </head> 
    
    <body>
            
        <div class="particles-js" id="particles-js"></div>
        <script>
            particlesJS.load('particles-js', "/static/core/particles.json", function() {
            console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });
        </script>
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="border">
                    <span class="large_text">Geometric Space Corporation</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content history">
                    <div class="content-box"><h2>History</h2>
                            <p>(GSC) is a recently formed subsidiary of Geometric Energy Corporation, a research and development firm founded in 2015. GSC provides cost-effective CubeSat rideshare programs, dedicated FireFly Alpha launches, and satellite data services.</p></div>
            </div>
            <center>
            <div class="launchbox">Countdown to Launch</div>
            <div class="countdown-wrapper"><div class="countdown" id="timer"></div></div> 
            <div class="button_wrapper"><div class="button dark">About This Launch</div><div class="button dark">Launch Schedule</div>
</div>
            </center>
            <div class="content mission">
                    <div class="content-box"><h2>Mission</h2>
                            <p>GSC ultimate ambition is to contribute to the creation of a multiplanetary civilization. The intermediary steps include optimizing current technology and expanding the commercial space market. It is those latter tasks on which the company is currently concentrating.</p></div>
            </div>
            <h1>Our Projects:</h1>
            <div class="three-columns">
                    
                    <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-title"><h2>Satellite Launch Services</h2></div>
                            <div class="panel-box">In 2021, Geometric Space launches Terraporta, the flagship software-as-a-service (SAAS) product capable of integrating with satellite data feeds from NASA, ESA, and JAXA.</div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-title"><h2>Dedicated FIrefly Alpha Launches</h2></div>
                            <div class="panel-box">In collaboration with our launch service provider, Firefly Aerospace, Geometric Space facilitates missions to low earth orbit for US and Canadian universities, private corporations, and government agencies.</div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="panel">
                            <div class="panel-title"><h2>Rideshare Programs for CubeSat Integration</h2></div>
                            <div class="panel-box">Geometric Space provides US and Canadian companies an affordable barrier for entry into the space market. Through an innovative blend of CubeSat form factor type payloads, multi-party integration, and mission cost optimization, Geometric Space minimizes financial requirements for space start-ups.</div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                    </div>
                    
            </div>
            <h1>The Team:</h1>
            <div class="three-columns">
                 
                <div class="panel-employee"><div class="image-wrapper"><div class="image-cropper"><img src="/media/employee_photos/sam-bf464855cdfd07858ca09ebf6b65d982.jpg" /></div></div><h2>Dan Ted</h2><h3>CTO</h3><div class="panel-box">Dan is the man ok just accept it</div></div>
                 
            </div>
</div>
<script> 
        var time = countdown(function(ts){
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML=ts.toHTML('div').replace(/,|and/gi,'')
        },new Date(2022, 6, 1), countdown.DAYS|countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS)
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you - that extra curly brace was accidentally inserted when I copied my code to SO. My actual code does not have that extra brace and I double checked. So I'm still getting this error. I've updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: Your welcome. Ok no worries. I will take a look at your updated post and edit my answer.

Comment: @Raven After running your updated code above, the media query works as expected and changes the background of `.content-box` to white with an opacity of 0.7 making it a grayish color for viewport widths that are less than 750px. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You are right - the code I posted works! But for some reason in the context of my full code it does not. I updated my post to include my entire HTML rather than just the relevant part. Here you can see that content-box is not responding to the change in window size. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sorry for this confusion, I think I found the problem. I was including my style sheet twice. Once all in the HTML, then again with an include! The second include did not contain the @media tag.

Comment: @Raven Your welcome! And don't worry about it. Have a look at my updated answer for what I found. Feel free to upvote or mark my answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.